# Deleting rows from Hive managed table partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

We have a managed partitioned table in Hive. Every partition has data for a date and contains 800-900 million rows. We recently noticed that data is around 200 partitions have got corrupt. To fix this, we want to delete certain rows from each of these 200 partition and reinsert them.

What is the best efficient and safe way of performing this?

We tried to insert overwrite the partitions without the bad rows, but dynamic partitioning threw out of memory error.

Comment: Could you post error log here to understand issue?

Comment: please post a query and log